# android seekbar height in drawable

Tags: android, xml

I have a seekbar which was very thick earlier. Later in the drawable i set height attribute and it is fine but it works only for SDK 23 or more.

SchedulePickupFragment.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/imgFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="in.junkart.junkart.SchedulePickupFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E4E4E4">

        <LinearLayout
            tools:context="in.junkart.junkart.SchedulePickupFragment"
            android:id="@+id/pickup_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/input_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textPersonName"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/input_phone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text|phone"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:hint="Phone"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_pickup_time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/input_pickup_time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:hint="Pickup Time"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="150sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Estimate Weight:"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"


                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/estmtWght"
                    android:layout_width="70sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="20 Kg"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:max="10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
                    >
                </SeekBar>





            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/input_address"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_locality"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/input_locality"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:hint="Locality"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/input_pin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:hint="Pin"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/input_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textAutoComplete"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                   android:paddingStart="15dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/input_message"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:hint="Message (If Any)"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingStart="15dp"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_schedule_pickup"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pickup_linearLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:src="@drawable/confirm_button_normal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />



        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- Fix user request form (weight, mandatory location - address autofill, state hidden field, locality, pincode)-->



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Progress.xml(in drawable)

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill"
    android:height="4dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:top="6dp">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:height="4dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:top="6dp">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill"/>

</item>
```

The height attribute in progress.xml seems to not work for sdk 22 and less.

Comment: use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar

Comment: How does this help? Doesn't seem to help me.